# Split Java String by New JTextFiled

Tags: java, regex, split, newline, jtextfield

My current MO No. JTextFiled include "1234567-001"
I want only "1234567" (7-digit) in one textFiled. 
Another "001" goes to next textFiled automatically.

Please refer to the screenshot for more details.

[Current Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zky0A.png)

[Excepted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEp7s.png)

Below here is my code that I tried:

```
txtMoNo = new JTextField();
        //set limit 7 key
        //txtMoNo.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(7));
        txtMoNo.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {


                //if (txtMoNo.getText().equals("")) {
                if (txtMoNo.getText().equals("") && txtMoNo.getText().contains("-")) {              

                    String MoNo = txtMoNo.getText();
                    String[] output = MoNo.split("-");
                    //String[] textMoNo = MoNo.split("\\r?\\n");
                    //String output = txtMoNo.getText();
                    //String[] splittext = output.split("-");
                    System.out.println("output split: " +output);
                    //String lines[] = string.split("\\r?\\n");

                    txtMoNo.setText("");            
                    txtItemNo.setText("");
                    txtItemNo.setText("");
                    txtCustomerPartNo.setText("");
                    txtCustomerName.setText("");
                    //txtPcsBag.setModel(new PcsBagData(new String[]{""}));
                    //txtPcsBag.setVisibleRowCount(1);
                    //txtBagSize.setText("");
                    //txtPcsCarton.setText("");
                    //txtCartonSize.setText("");
                    tablePacks.setModel(new PackingSpecNoData("", ""));
                    txtPackingDate.setText("");
                } else {
                    SwingWorker<?, ?> job = new UIQuery();
                    job.execute();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(txtMoNo, "cell 1 1,growx");
        txtMoNo.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: any event where it should split? or just once the first textfield holds 7 characters move to the next?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer .just one textField 7 characters and move to next textField automatically by ignoring "-".

Comment: `txtMoNo.getText().equals("") && txtMoNo.getText().contains("-")` this can never be true, if your text equals `""` (in other words, is empty) then it cant contain a `-`.

Comment: @SWoeste..how should I modify my code #_#

Comment: do you want to split after 7 characters or on the `-`sign?

Comment: @SWoeste..yes..After 7 characters, split and goes to next textField. 
But next filed dont include "-" sign.

Comment: at first you could start to modify your if like this `if (txtMoNo.getText().length() >= 7)` also you should have a look at the `substring` method of `String`.

Comment: is the `-` mandatory? or can it be left out while typing? i have a solution to move focus after 7 chars but not for the `-`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer... let me know how is the solution first coz I tried so many times still did not go automatically to nextField after 7 chars. #_#

Comment: @advanex125 have a look at my answer. also found a solution for the `-`

Answer (score 0):

i have written a simple test class with only 2 `JTextField`'s. Once the first textfield has 7 characters, the second one will grab the focus and ignore the `-` key completely. If you want to have it in any other position of the textfield you will need another solution. code is as follows:

```
public Test() {
    super();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField();

    t1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            if (t1.getText().length() == 7) {
                t2.grabFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    t2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (c == '-') {
                e.consume(); // ignore event
            }
        }
    });

    this.add(t1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    this.add(t2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```